# Tell a Java Class<T> that T has a certain method in it

Tags: java, class, generics, types

I am currently implementing an algorithm to generate High Variance clusters in a dataset.  Throughout my different tests, I will be using many different data types, so I need to make my Cluster class usable for any data type T. So, I have:

```
public class Cluster<T> {
    private int score;
    private ArrayList<T> list;
    private int k;
```

and to be able to assess the effectiveness of this algorithm, we have a score that is computed based on the distance between each object in the cluster.  Here is the computeScore() method:

```
private void computeScore() {
    if (list.size() < 2) score = 0;
    else if (list.size() == 2) {
        T x = list.remove(1);
        T y = list.remove(0);
        score = x.distanceTo(y);
        list.add(y);
        list.add(x);
    }
}
```

The problem is that in the computeScore() method, the line `score = x.distanceTo(y)` throws an error because for type T, the distanceTo() method is undefined.  For all of my datatypes, I will be defining this method for use here.  How do I tell the Cluster class, that distanceTo() will be defined?

Thanks in advance for your help.

Comment: Where are you defining the `distanceTo` method? Is it in some super type for all the supported type?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

I guess you could use `<T extends YourClass>` and define `distanceTo()` in `YourClass`.

Comment: Yep, just baseclass it.

Comment: I'd probably define an `interface` that declares `distanceTo`.  But it's pretty much the same solution.

Comment: that seems to work, however I would need to extend it to all data type classes that I use.  I think I am going to implement a Class called DataType that just includes distanceTo() and all my data type classes will inherit DataType.  Then T will just extend DataType.

Answer (score 0):

This can be achieved with reflection;

something like... `x.getClass().getMethod("distanceTo", (Class<?>[]) T).invoke(x);`